# How to upgrade the BIOS of Mac Mini 2007

Tags: windows-7, bios, upgrade, mac-mini

How to upgrade the BIOS of Mac Mini (2007) with windows 7 Ultimate updated (32 bit, IE version 9.0.8112.16421) and boot camp (no Mac OS) ?

I have installed Windows 7 32 bit ultimate with Boot Camp v3.3 on my Mac Mini (2007) Kindly advise me how to upgrade the BIOS. There is no Mac operating system.

Answer (score 6):

There is no BIOS on your Mac Mini.  Only EFI.

That said, the [files to update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1237) the EFI are here at Apple.

**That** said, you are out of luck, as there is no non-OSX way to update the EFI.  There is no Windows based tool for this, there is no hack in place for this.

You must remember that Apple builds their computers to run **their** operating system.  Yes, due to customer demands, they have provided a minimal amount of support for people who want to use another Operating System along side their OS... but the intent of Apple is not to build a generic computer that anyone can put any OS on and use any way they want.  The intention of Apple is to build the computer **they** envision, running the OS **they** design and support.

So... you can't really get upset with Apple if they don't provide a generic solution to updating the EFI, when what they want is for you to use their OS to update their EFI.

Comment: Yup, the only correct answer. I wonder what made the OP think they'd even need to update the BIOS? DrWho, can you clarify?

Comment: Thank you all very much for the extremely useful clarifications. I tried for updating the BIOS because it takes more than 2 minutes to boot up even after minimizing the startup programs. The display remains pure white color for the initial 1 minute and then it changes to black with a blinking cursor for the next 1 minute. Only later windows starting up screen appears. I installed Windows 7 on this Mac mini (which I received as a gift) because all my other 4 computers are windows based and so working on files on different computers would be easy for me if the OS is same.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying that you don't meet the requirements for Windows 7, because according to this http://support.apple.com/kb/SP7 you do... but those specs are a bit low... especially if you didn't upgrade anything.  Specifically, the 1gb Ram, 64mb of which is shared with the system Ram.  This could have something to do with the longer boot time.  Now, some Mac Minis were shipped with Core Duo (not Core 2 Duo) processors, which makes them incompatible with OSX Lion, which according to Apple, makes them incompatible with Windows 7.  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1899 Odd that.